# Any possible way to shorten this if statement of Python?

Tags: python, if-statement

I was having trouble to shorten the if statement for a Python question from CodingBat.
The question goes like this: Given an array of ints, return True if one of the first 4 elements in the array is a 9. The array length may be less than 4.
The original code I wrote works fine and it looked like this:

```
def array_front9(nums):
  if len(nums) >= 4:
    count = 4
  else:
    count = len(nums)
  for n in range(count):
    if nums[n] == 9:
      return True
  return False
```

I tried to shorten if and else between line 2 and line 4:

```
def array_front9(nums):
    return count = 4 if len(nums) >= 4 else count = len(nums)
  for n in range(count):
    if nums[n] == 9:
      return True
  return False
```

However, it became an invalid syntax after I changed it. I am not sure where I did it wrong. Is there any way to shorten between line 2 and line 4?
Thanks!

Comment: Use a ternary operator. `count = 4 if len(nums) >= 4 else count = len(nums)`

Comment: Okay, so you want to cause `count` to become equal either to `4` or to `len(nums)`, depending. Does that involve `return`ing from the function? No? Then why does your attempt include the `return` keyword? Simply remove that, and you have it right.

Comment: `count = len(nums[:4])`.

Comment: That said: the question is intended to test whether you understand *slicing* in Python. You don't need any conditional logic at all.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel yeah, I understand the intention of this question. I just want to know more  about if statement.

Comment: I changed my code like below, and it showed up with "can't assign to conditional expression".
`def array_front9(nums):
    count = 4 if len(nums) >= 4 else count = len(nums)
    for n in range(count):
        if nums[n] == 9:
            return True
    return False`

Answer (score 4):

Regarding your code:

- the indentation is wrong. The first `return` statement has an indent of 4 while the `for` statement has an indentation of 2 only.
- the first `return` statement cannot be an assignment at the same time.
- the `if/else` construct does not need a second assignment. Just put the number in the else block. The assignment is already at the beginning of the line

So your code becomes

```
def array_front9(nums):
    count = 4 if len(nums) >= 4 else len(nums)
    for n in range(count):
        if nums[n] == 9:
            return True
    return False
```

There's an even shorter solution:

```
def array_front9(nums):
    return 9 in nums[0:4]
```

`in` is the keyword to check if an element is found in an array. With slicing `[0:4]`, you limit that to the first 4 elements of the array. This still works if the array is shorter.

Comment: oh wow, I think I understand where I got it wrong. And thanks for mentioning the indentation.

Answer (score 1):

Something like that should be possible:

```py
def array_front9(nums):
    count = 4 if len(nums) >= 4 else len(nums)
    return any(nums[n] == 9 for n in range(count))
```

Comment: `array_front9([1,2,9])` returns `True`. Why would an `IndexError` be raised ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't return an assignment in Python:

```py
In [14]: def func():
    ...:     return count = 4
  File "<ipython-input-14-918fc0e49446>", line 2
    return count = 4
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Thomas is also correct in that you have code after your `return` statement, which is incorrectly indented and won't run anyway since it's after a return, although Python won't complain.

If you want to use your original ternary idea:

```py
In [20]: def array_front9(nums):
    ...:     return 4 if len(nums) >= 4 else len(nums)

In [21]: array_front9([1,2,3])
Out[21]: 3

In [22]: array_front9([1,2,3,4])
Out[22]: 4

In [23]: array_front9([1,2,3,4,5])
Out[23]: 4
```

Answer (score 0):

checkout this out: https://jaxenter.com/implement-switch-case-statement-python-138315.html
It's called a switch statement, this can make if else blocks simpler.